# Status Notifier plugin does not display application icons after Xfce upgrade

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, xfce

I upgraded from Xubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. Now, the Status Notifier plugin stopped displaying all the applications that used to appear there (Network Manager, Skype, Telegram, etc.) If I remove it from the panel and add it back, the applications appear again. Did someone have the same issue?

Comment: You need to add "notification area plugin" instead for 20.04. Also, network monitor comes as a separate plug-in now. 20.04 you'll need to use indicator-plugin for indicator-messages.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was consistently reproduced; now, it is not happening anymore. I ran some `apt-get upgrade` for other reasons; I believe it may have solved that. Not only that, now I don't need the Status Notifier widget: the Notification Area widget displays everything I need.